# python: execute a .py file multiple times?

Tags: python, loops, execute

I have about 50 lines of code, which isn't based on any looping variable (which is why I cannot do for loop) but I want to run this code several times so that my output array keeps building up in length. Is there any way to do that? I would like to execute this .py file 10,000 times. Let me know how I can do that. I know normally I would execute it on my terminal by typing

execfile('filename.py')

but how to do this several times?
Thank you!

example of what's in the .py file:say I have a bunch of distributions I want to calculate chi sq value for, and save all the values in an array chi = [] after the 10,000 iterations, how would I do that for this case?

```
chi = []
def chisqg(ydata,ymod,sd=None):  

    if sd==None:  
        chisq=np.sum((ydata-ymod)**2)  
    else:  
        chisq=np.sum( ((ydata-ymod)/sd)**2 )  
    return chisq

chi1 = chisqg(y1,mod1,sd=0.1)
chi.append(chi1)
```

Comment: Do you have a list of `y1,mod1` etc. values you want to run your function on? Where are those coming from? As it is running it 10k times will just get you the same value.

Aside: what's up with the drive-by downvotes? This is a reasonable beginner question.

Comment: what down votes? I'm not aware of what you're talking about. and yes, the y1, mod1 are basically np.random.normal distribution functions. just need to gather chi sq values comparing the two over and over for 10,000 times.

Comment: oh you mean negative votes? yea I always lose points on stack overflow for asking questions, guess the community isn't that welcoming of beginners :'(

Comment: It's not clear why you think you cannot use a loop.

Comment: There's an aversion on this site to "doing homework" or helping out when it seems like the asker hasn't made any effort to solve problems themselves, but it can be unnecessarily harsh to people who are just starting out.

Comment: this isn't for homework. I cannot post my entire code that's in the .py file due to security reasons for research. just starting out in python so would definitely appreciate all the help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you think a loop won't work here; if you want your `chi` variable to end up with 10k entries in it you can just change the last lines of your file to:

```
for i in range(10000):
    chi1 = chisqg(y1,mod1,sd=0.1)
    chi.append(chi1)
```

Comment: ok awesome!! I tweaked it a little bit but this idea worked! thank you so very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(10000):
  execfile("filename.py")
```

Comment: but where should I be using the global variable i?

Comment: There's no requirement to actually *use* the loop index. This code will simply iterate 10000 times, without actually looking at the value of `i` on each iteration.

Comment: so i did try this, but seems like in the end, the array chi only ends up with one value, not with 10,000 values. how do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Oh, I see now what you are trying to do.  I think tzaman answer is the correct one.

Comment: The file you execute resets `chi` to an empty list each time. You'll need to reorganize your code a bit to make it truly reusable.

Comment: You should use `_` for throwaway variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not looking to execute the file simultaneously then the simplest way is to use:

on windows:

```
for x in range(0, 30):
    %run -i "insert_your_file.py"
```

on Linux or OsX

```
for x in range(0, 30):
    %run -i 'insert_your_file.py'
```

***yes the double quotes matter.

For more info on %run:
[enter link description here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

This is similar to running at a system prompt python file args, but with the advantage of giving you IPython’s tracebacks, and of loading all variables into your interactive namespace for further use (unless -p is used, see below).

The file is executed in a namespace initially consisting only of **name**=='**main**' and sys.argv constructed as indicated. It thus sees its environment as if it were being run as a stand-alone program (except for sharing global objects such as previously imported modules). But after execution, the IPython interactive namespace gets updated with all variables defined in the program (except for **name** and sys.argv). This allows for very convenient loading of code for interactive work, while giving each program a ‘clean sheet’ to run in.